# Can't determine break line character in textarea

Tags: php, xml, textarea, entity, line-breaks

The user in my website will open up a form with a `<textarea>` where they will type text, likely with multiple paragraphs. Once they submit, the text will be available in a HTML page, each paragraph inside `<p>` tags. They may go back on a later date and make changes to what they wrote, which will have been stored in .xml files.

I'm new with creating and editing .xml files with php, but that seems to be in order. What I've been having nightmares with is breaking down what is in the textarea by paragraphs into different nodes. What I've been using when loading the page with the form is

```
$pageElements = array('title','subtitle','parag');
// [...]

foreach($pageElements as $element){
   $temp = $page->getElementsByTagName($element);
   foreach($temp as $node){
      $t[$element][] = $node->nodeValue;
   }
}

// [...]
$t['parag'] = implode('&#10;&#10;',$t['parag']);
```

This will display the paragraphs in the `<textarea>` separated with double break lines, so it is what I want so far. But when the user submits the form I use the following code to insert the paragraphs back into the .xml:

```
// [ delete all nodes from that page ]
$t['parag'] = explode('&#10;&#10;',$_POST['parag']);
// [...]
foreach($t['parag'] as $parag){
    $parags->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($parag));
}
```

When I go look in the .xml file, there is a single node for all the paragraphs, and they are separated by `&#13;` and a line break in the file. It seems to me that when the browser (I tried both Chrome and Firefox) finds `&#10;`, it converts it to some other line break character and I can't find what that is to explode it back to an array. If I load the page with the form again, it will break the string into paragraphs, but when I start writing the code for the other page in which I'll want to place each paragraph in a `<p>`, I'll need them separated.

I looked in many posts in this site with no luck. I have also tried all combinations of the following:

```
$t['parag'] = implode('&#13;&#13;',$t['parag']);
$t['parag'] = implode('&#13;\n',$t['parag']);
$t['parag'] = implode('\n',$t['parag']);
$t['parag'] = implode('&#10;\n',$t['parag']);
$t['parag'] = implode('\n\r',$t['parag']);
$t['parag'] = implode('\r\n',$t['parag']);
$t['parag'] = implode('&#13;&#10;',$t['parag']);
$t['parag'] = implode('&#10;&#13;',$t['parag']);

$t['parag'] = explode('&#13;&#13;',$_POST['parag']);
$t['parag'] = explode('&#13;&#10;',$_POST['parag']);
$t['parag'] = explode('&#13;\n',$_POST['parag']);
$t['parag'] = explode('&#13;\r',$_POST['parag']);
$t['parag'] = explode('\n\r',$_POST['parag']);
$t['parag'] = explode('\r\n',$_POST['parag']);
$t['parag'] = explode('<br />',nl2br($_POST['parag']));
```

I think I tried all combinations of `&#13;` `&#10;` `\n` and `\r` and they always resulted in `&#13;` and a line break in the xml file. Now I'm lost.

Does any one know what I should use to implode and explode to get the desired effect?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: got it! with `chr(13) . chr(10) . chr(13) . chr(10)` for both imploding and exploding; nothing like being fresh in the morning... should I delete the topic?

Comment: You can add that as an answer to your own question.